# can't access value of input when i have it inside foreach loop (using post method)

Tags: php, forms, post, foreach

I have a form contains one input (type button) and one image.
when i click on the button it supposed to delete the image (submit the form and get the value of the input which is the id of the image, using post method).
But i can't access the value of the input when i have it inside foreach loop.
because every input created inside foreach has the same name.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D2Wu.png

i tried var_dump and there is just null value.

this is the form inside the camera view:

```
foreach($data['galleries'] as $gallery) :
    ?>
    <div align=center>
    <form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/gelleries/camera" 
   method="post">
    <input type="button" class="button" name="delete" id="abc" 
   value="<?php echo $gallery->galleryId; ?>" onclick="return 
   Deleteqry(<?php echo $gallery->galleryId; ?>);">
    </div>
    </form>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this is the controller:

```
<?php
    class Galleries extends Controller {
     $this->galleryModel = $this->model('Gallery');
   }
    $galleries = $this->galleryModel->hiFive();
    $datashow = [
        'galleries' => $galleries
    ];
    .....
    public function camera(){
     if (isset($_POST['delete']) && !empty($_POST["delete"])){
        $imgid = $_POST["delete"];
      $this->galleryModel->deleteimg($imgid);
      echo "deleted!";
    exit;
 }
 else
    echo "error";
    $this->view('/galleries/camera', $datashow);
 }
```

and this is the model where i execute the queries:

```
<?php
   class Gallery {
   private $db;

   public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new Database;
   }
   .....
      public function deleteimg($id){
       $this->db->query("DELETE FROM galleries WHERE id = :id");
       $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
       if($this->db->execute()){
       return true;
     } else {
      return false;
   }
   }
   }
```

The Deleteqry inside onclick event of the button it's just a function where i check if i get the id of the image when i click on the button:

```
function Deleteqry(id)
{ 
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")==true)

 window.location="http://localhost:8001/camagru/galleries/camera? 
 &del="+id;
  return false;
 }
```

Comment: creating multiple forms in a loop is more or less OK but you MUST ensure that any elements that have an ID attribute have a unique ID rather than `id="abc"` etc

Comment: @RamRaider i changed now with <?php echo $gallery->galleryId; ?> .. so every element has unique id .. but i still can't remove the image

Comment: what does `Deleteqry` do? You have not added that to the question

Comment: it's just a javascript function where i check if i get the id of every image when i click on the button .. i add it now on the post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hidden input field in your form block with value of gallery ID, like this:

```
 <form ...>
    <input type="button" class="button" name="delete" value="DELETE NOW">
    <input type="hidden" name="GallID" value="<?php echo $gallery->galleryId;?>" >
 </form>
```

And in your controller read that value from hidden field:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['GallID']) && !empty($_POST["delete"])){
    $imgid = $_POST["GallID"];
    $this->galleryModel->deleteimg($imgid);
    echo "deleted!";
}
```

This works completly without javascript.